# Iptables is constantly in loop and banning same IP indefinite

Tags: 22.04, iptables

1 IP is constantly banned and added to iptables, it fills my iptables with 50.000+ of DROP lines for "Same" ip.

How is this possible? If 1 IP is banned and goes to drop rule, that ip should not be able to reach server anymore and should not be added many times with same rule.

This is causing adding 50k+ lines in iptable rules and causing my cpu load average to go crazy after my server needs reboot.

1. Do you know how can i check which process/script is triggering iptables?
2. Is it possible to disable iptables completely temporarily since adding rules constantly is causing my cpu load average to go crazy and cause server crash?

I am grateful for any advice

Comment: You do not know what is modifying iptables, is that correct?

Comment: Have you upgraded to 22.04 from 18.04? Your original question about this, since closed, said 18.04. Check for any clues in `/var/log/auth.log`. Is fail2ban running?

Comment: yes i did upgrade but issue still persist.

Comment: @OrganicMarble correct, i am not sure what is causing iptables rules to be added

Comment: are you using fail2ban?

Comment: how do i check it, i did not setup anything specific, it is default installation?